# IE Dynamically Added Button Not Calling On Click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have some code that dynamically creates a new button through JavaScript that when clicked calls a JavaScript function.  The code works just as expected in Firefox, Chrome, Opera but low and behold, it doesn't work in IE(7 - I'm not even going to bother with IE6).

The button gets created and appears, but it's not calling the onclick event.

```
var newButton = document.createElement('input');
newButton.setAttribute('id','btnChat_');
newButton.setAttribute('type','button');
newButton.setAttribute('onclick','askQuestion()');
newButton.setAttribute('value', 'Respond');
document.getElementById('frmChat').appendChild(newButton);
```

Does anyone know why this won't work in IE, or have a suggestion as to how I could write this code so it will work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try avoiding use of setAttribute and just do

```
newButton.onclick = function(){ askQuestion(); };
```

Comment: Bug: you can't set any inline event handlers using setAttribute() in IE.

Answer (score 0):

That will work in firefox, IE is slightly different try

```
newButton.onclick = function() {askQuestion();};
```

OR

```
newButton.onclick = new Function('askQuestion()');
```

That should work as I have gotten it to work.  If that STILL doesn't do it, then YUI has an event framework in which you would do this

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(newButton,'click',askQuestion);
```

See http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/event/eventsimple.html for more examples.

Comment: No love with either of those.

Comment: Damn, someone beat me too it!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, use it. Not only will this make manipulating the DOM easier, it will let you simply say `$('#myNewButton').click(function(){//hey});`

and be sure it works.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Yes, it would easier to use jQuery, but this is a generic JavaScript question - and jQuery isn't practical in every environment.

Comment: I would like to do more with JQuery, but I have a pretty good understanding of how to do things in JavaScript without, so that's how I usually approach things.  One of these days I'll get around to deeply understanding JQuery.

Comment: Not knowing is the worst reason for not using. Spend the 30 minutes to sharpen the axe before taking down the great oak. Please.

@Jason: Sure, it's not appropriate where jquery isn't possible (a browserless javascript parser, for instance), but that clearly isn't the case here.

Comment: In this case, not knowing is a very good reason because I'm doing some pretty crazy interactions with AJAX and other things where I really want to be able to understand what's going on at the lower level.  I think JQuery would abstract too much of that away for me and end up causing me problems of leaky abstractions.

Also, this is on a very tight deadline, so at the moment there isn't enough time to "sharpen the axe" and still get the project out the door on time.